# Can't find enable/disable option for package duplicatation on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I rencently upgraded my gitlab-ce to 13.12 because i saw this [feature](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#allow-or-prevent-duplicate-generic-package-uploads), and realised I don't have Packages & Registries in my settings.
Is there anything i miss here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that this is a `GROUP LEVEL` setting and *not* a project level setting.

To change this select the Group containing the project, where you want this feature. Within the settings for the group, you will find a section called `Packages and Registries`.

[image: screenshot of settings]